# What was the story behind Deep Purple's "Smoke on the Water"?

Tags: history

It was 1971 in Montreux close to where I live. But it wasn't me who ...

We've got just married in that time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The story is pretty well covered by these sources. The wikipedia article quotes further sources, if you want to get into more detail

- [NPR
  broadcast](https://www.npr.org/sections/parallels/2015/03/08/391246315/a-swiss-town-a-casino-fire-and-smoke-on-the-water?t=1571162510610)
- [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_on_the_Water)

The wikipedia article has this :

> " On 4 December 1971, Purple were in Montreux, Switzerland, to record
>   an album using a mobile recording studio (rented from the Rolling
>   Stones and known as the Rolling Stones Mobile Studio—referred to as
>   the "Rolling truck Stones thing" and "a mobile" in the lyrics) at the
>   entertainment complex that was part of the Montreux Casino (referred
>   to as "the gambling house" in the song lyric).
>
> On the eve of the
>   recording session, a Frank Zappa and The Mothers of Invention concert
>   was held in the casino's theatre. This was to be the theatre's final
>   concert before the casino complex closed down for its annual winter
>   renovations, which would allow Deep Purple to record there.
>
> At the
>   beginning of Don Preston's synthesizer solo on "King Kong", the place
>   suddenly caught fire when somebody in the audience fired a flare gun
>   toward the rattan covered ceiling, as mentioned in the "some stupid
>   with a flare gun" line. Although there were no major injuries, the
>   resulting fire destroyed the entire casino complex, along with all the
>   Mothers' equipment.
>
> The "smoke on the water" that became the title of
>   the song (credited to bass guitarist Roger Glover, who related how the
>   title occurred to him when he woke from a dream a few days later)
>   referred to the smoke from the fire spreading over Lake Geneva from
>   the burning casino as the members of Purple watched from their hotel.
>   "It was probably the biggest fire I'd ever seen up to that point and
>   probably ever seen in my life" said Glover. "It was a huge building. I
>   remember there was very little panic getting out, because it didn't
>   seem like much of a fire at first. But, when it caught, it went up
>   like a fireworks display."
>
> The "Funky Claude" running in and out is
>   referring to Claude Nobs, the director of the Montreux Jazz Festival
>   who helped some of the audience escape the fire."